# Notifiactions are not getting in MI, Oneplus, Lenovo Mobiles

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

*I am developing an android app, In that I have incorporated Push Notifications When some action performed in the web app I send a notification to the registered user(Push is incorporated using Amazon AWS). To configure these push notifications I have used cordova PushPlugin. If the application is in background, then I am getting the notifications. But If I close the app from recent apps try then Notifications are not firing. I want to how Facebook and Whatsapp apps are sending notifications if the app is terminated. I am using cordova and ionic framework to develop the hybrid mobile app. Anyone help is appreciated!*